# How do I get the status code & response headers of a jersey/dropwizard response, when testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jersey, dropwizard

I'm working on unit tests (backed by mocks) for my dropwizard resources. I recently added some response headers and different status codes, and want to test those.

Unfortunately I can't find an example in their documentation where they get both the entity and examine the response.

The method I'm testing streams back a file. The method itself is defined as:

```
@GET
@Path("/{assetId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@PermitAll
public Response download(@Auth User user,
                         @PathParam("assetId") String assetId,
                         @HeaderParam("Range") String rangeHeader) {
```

To verify the download, I was initially making a request from my test like this:

```
    final InputStream responseStream = resource.client()
        .target("/assets/123")
        .request()
        .get(InputStream.class);
```

I could then write the stream to a file and validate that it was the file being returned from the resource. Worked fine. (Here, "resource" is dropwizard's ResourceTestRule.)

However, as above, I now want to get a handle on the response itself. There are examples floating around which use Jersey's ClientResponse, but that doesn't work (yet). I tried:

```
    final ClientResponse response = resource.client()
        .target("/assets/123")
        .request()
        .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

However, this ends up with an exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.

at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:811)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
```

...which I'm not sure what to do with. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, this was simpler than I thought.

```
    final Response response = resource.client()
        .target("/assets/123")
        .request()
        .get();

    InputStream responseStream = (InputStream) response.getEntity();
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it's solving the problem. That way the others readers will have visual notification that there is a solution to the described problem.